# MySQL: return first row from join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables "quizzes" & "users", I need to return list of first user took each quiz, with quiz_id:

tables structure

```
"quizzes" structure:
id     name
1     England
2     france
3     Japan
4     USA
5     UAE
6     Sweden
7     Italy
8     Brazil
9     South Korea
10    India


"users" structure:
id    user_id     quiz_id
1       1            1
2       1            2
3       2            1
4       3            4
5       1            4
6       5            9
7       2            9
8       3            8
9       3            9
10      3            7
```

I need to run query to return first "user_id" took each "quiz", (order by users.id ASC)

```
expected results:
quiz_id     user_id
   1           1
   2           1
   4           3
   7           3
   8           3
   9           5
```

thanks,

Comment: Join on a subqery with MIN(user_id).... GROUP BY quiz_id

Comment: @Mihai pls, can u provide full query?

Comment: This is a classic [greatest-n-per-group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column) (or least, in this case) problem, of which there are many existing solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first group by `quiz` and pick minimal `id` and then select based on those `ids`:

```
select quiz_id, user_id
from users 
where id in(select min(id) from users group by quiz_id)
```

Comment: thx, but is there way to select them based on "date" ASC, rather than "min(id)" ?

Comment: Sure you can do this.

Comment: @mwafi . . . Your question here has no mention of a date column.  If you have another question, ask it as another question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select quiz_id, user_id
  from users
    Where  (quiz_id, id) in
       (
       Select quiz_id, min(id) id
         From users
           Group by quiz_id
       )
```

Comment: While you filter by id, filtering by quiz is just overhead.